# Select all fields that are true

Tags: web2py

I have a user database and a fruit database the user fills in a form of tick boxes to select what fruit they have.

In a profile I would like to reflect this information but I can't figure out how I would query the database in web2py to show all boolean fields that are set to `True`.

Can it be done with a SQL query or do I need to filter the results from selecting the users fruit record?

Here is my DB model:

```
db.define_table('fruit',
    Field('id', 'reference auth_user'),
    Field('apple','boolean',label=T('Apple')),
    Field('apricot','boolean',label=T('Apricot')),
    Field('cherry','boolean',label=T('Cherry')),
    Field('fig','boolean', label=T('Fig')),
    Field('lychee','boolean', label=T('Lychee')),
    Field('peach','boolean', label=T('Peach')),
    Field('pear','boolean', label=T('Pear')),
    Field('plum','boolean', label=T('Plum')))
```

Here is my controller (obviously it doesn't work. It just returns `<Set 0>`).

I have tried a few different combinations from Googling but none have the desired results:

```
def profile():

    id = auth.user.id or redirect(URL('default', 'index'))
    user = db.auth_user[id]
    fruit = db.fruit(id=id)
    produce = db(fruit == True)
    return dict(user=user, produce=produce)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fruit = db.fruit(id=id)
```

Above, `fruit` is a DAL Row object (which behaves much like a dictionary).

```
produce = db(fruit == True)
```

Above, `db(fruit == True)` is how you would specify a DAL Set, and the `fruit == True` part would be a DAL Query, but it doesn't make sense to use a Row object in a query. In any case, you don't want a Set object, as such objects do not include any data -- they merely define a set of records (without retrieving them).

It's not clear what type of data structure you are looking for, but if you want a list of fruit names that have been checked, you could try:

```
produce = [field for field in fruit if fruit[field] is True]
```

The above list comprehension iterates through the field names and keeps those for which the value associated with the field is `True` (this will automatically skip any non-boolean fields, as only boolean fields store the actual values `True` and `False`).